# Which Wix API call can I use to update my restaurant order scheduling rules?

Tags: rest, e-commerce, api-design, velo

I have a WIX Restaurant that only takes pre-orders online and delivers every Tuesday. Due to the nature of when I change the menu to the next week's, this requires me to manually update my Scheduling Rules (specifically the "At most ... days in advance" field) twice per week.

Reading through the [Wix API Reference](https://dev.wix.com/docs/rest/api-reference/wix-restaurants/orders/introduction), there doesn't seem to be an API call listed for this exact operation to be automated. Once I find the right command, I will run it on a scheduler since I've already generated the API key.

Could someone please point me in the right direction as I have been trying to figure this out for a long time and their documentation and especially technical support have been... less than stellar.

[image]